# Converting 3D contour points to 3D binary volume

Tags: matlab, triangulation

I have a set of 3D contour points that represent a closed surface, such as the following:

[image: 3D contour points]

The contour slices are closed curves, and are always located at integer z values. Although, there are some z values in the middle that don't have contours.

In MATLAB, I want to convert this point representation to a binary volume representation, where pixels that lie inside of the contour shape are considered as 1, and pixels outside as 0.

I tried 3D triangulation and then converting the triangulated polygon to a binary volume. Although, the triangulation doesn't respect the boundary limits that are imposed by the closed curves on each slice. That is, the intra-slice points are connected indiscriminately and some round features are lost.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check [Marching Cubes](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/) and [Ball Pivoting](http://www.research.ibm.com/vistechnology/pdf/bpa_tvcg.pdf) for 3D triangulation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to obtain the triangulation that I wanted by using Ball Pivoting filtering in [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/).